# How to validate props passed to an anonymous component in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, formik

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
          specialist: '',
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values));
          // setSubmitting(true);
        }}
        validationSchema={createAppointmentSchema}
      >
        {props => {
          const {
            values,
            errors,
            isSubmitting,
            handleChange,
            handleSubmit,
            setFieldValue
          } = props;
          return (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormItem>
                <Span>Seleccione un Especialista</Span>
              </FormItem>
            ....
            </Form>
           );
         }
       }
</Formik>
```

In have a configuration to throw an error when props is not validated in my .eslintrc file. But when we use Formik, since it uses render-props pattern, so that it calls my component as a child and passing props to it. My question is how to validate the props that Formik passed to my component?

```
  151:13  error    'values' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
  152:13  error    'errors' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
  153:13  error    'isSubmitting' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  154:13  error    'handleChange' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  155:13  error    'handleSubmit' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types
  156:13  error    'setFieldValue' is missing in props validation   react/prop-types
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is misleading, I made the same "mistake". It's not props in the general sense of React props so your linter is confused. You can call it anything, it's the object passed into the function. I would probably just deconstruct the variables you need. So something like:

```js
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ specialist: '' }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
        // setSubmitting(true);
      }}
      validationSchema={createAppointmentSchema}
    >
      {({ values, handleSubmit }) => {
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormItem>
            <Span>Seleccione un Especialista</Span>
          </FormItem>
          ....
        </Form>;
      }}
    </Formik>
```